# Rename image that has been picked by imagepicker for flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, imagepicker

I would like to rename the file that i already pick from my gallery by image picker, i already try the below method using renameAsync

```
String dir = path.dirname(pickedFile.path);
String newName = path.join(dir, 'customname.jpg');
File(pickedFile.path).renameSync(newName);
```

however it return error [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot rename file to ....